# New php files not working on cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel, centos6

So I have a website where I have many files all of them are written in php and works perfectly fine, except the new files, whenever I create a new php file and run it from the browser it show 500 Internal server error. I have tried removing all the content from php file and echoed a single line but I got the same error. I created a local php.ini file for that particular domain and tried to turn the errors on but nothing really changed. Don't know what to do to find what is wrong.

Comment: are you saving the files in the right place?

Comment: Check your server's error logs. These will likely be in `/var/logs/apache/` (though cPanel might put them elsewhere; if it does, you'll have to look in the docs to find out where). That will give you the error that you're getting. If you still need help after you find the error, then copy the error text here and we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: Check your php error logs , your php.ini file will have the location where the logs are being saved

Comment: Sounds like it is permissions related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to permission, php files need to be executable:

- Directories and folders should be set to 755.
- Executable scripts within the cgi-bin folder must be set to 755.
- Images, media, and text files like HTML should be set to 644.

You can use command `chmod` to set the proper permission.